# Повреждение файла во время записи

Tags: c#

Может ли при перезаписи файла - например .json произойти что то - что его повредит ?

- При отказе какого то компонента.
- Во время отключения пк во время записи
- И что то другое

Если да, как этого избежать ?

Comment: Может. Записывайте во временный файл в той же папке, а после записи перемещайте в нужное место

Comment: @andreymal да. я думал об этом, тогда вопрос, при переносе проблем возникнуть никаких не может ?

Comment: @andreymal сохранить / копировать / удалить временный) ?

Comment: Не копировать, а именно переместить, это важно. Линукс гарантирует атомарность перемещения (насчёт винды не уверен)

Comment: Правда, остаётся открытым вопрос, что если вырубить ПК ровно во время перемещения. Возможно, журнал файловой системы завершит перемещение или вернёт всё как было, но точно не уверен

Comment: естественно может, запись в файл не атомарная операция (открытие+запись по частям). но очень быстрая. тем более маленький json файл. с учетом буферизованой записи, скорей все за один раз все из памяти туда запишется (буфер будет накапливаться в памяти, а реально ничего писаться не будет до какого-то предела в килобайтах). если не рассматривать выключение пк (это явно ненормальная ситуация), то для возникновение исключения в процессе записи нужно очень постараться написать такой код (скажем сначала открыть файл, а только потом сериализовать объект в строку с ошибкой и вылететь с исключением).

Comment: @АлексейОбухов да - понимаю что не нормальная, но если будет, для меня будет фатальной. Вопрос, как железно избежать ? Наверняка есть какие то паттерны.

Comment: @Xzizz железно избежать вряд ли получится, потому что создать проблемы могут даже баги в прошивке накопителя, и с этим уже ничего не поделать, кроме как старательно бэкапить

Comment: Берем файл, переименовываем с расширением .backup, пишем на его место новый. В следующий раз смотрим, если .backup существует, удаляем, текущий переименовываем в .backup, пишем новые данные. Проще простого. А так если хотите железно - используйте базу данных с репликацией на другой физический носитель или вообще на другой сервер. Все остальные риски закрываются источником бесперебойного питания. Меня репликация уже спасала.

Comment: @aepot Понял - спасибо, руки не дотягиваются базы данных изучить, до сегодняшнего дня в задачах хватало просто на диске в папках и под папках в json хранить. Но пришла задача с хранением годовых историй, вот и задумался) Пока с бекапом как вы описали сделаю, затем перейду на базу - ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: @aepot с файлом .backup плохой подход, потому что не атомарный. Вариант с переименованием (если не брать в расчёт баги) допускает ровно два варианта: или целый старый файл, или целый новый файл — никаких промежуточных вариантов

Comment: @andreymal почему плохой? Ну можно какой-нибудь .lock файл создать пустой, чтобы при последующей загрузке понять, что транзакция не была завершена и запустить дополнительную валидацию сохраненных данных. Смысл здесь в том что если даже файл не записался, бэкап всегда будет живой.

Comment: @aepot если временный файл, описанный в первом комментарии, не записался, то старый файл тоже будет живой — причём по правильному пути, так что костылять с предварительным переименованием в .backup не только бессмысленно, но и вредно

Comment: @andreymal а если он записался на половину? Не понимаю вас. В первый раз слышу, что делать бэкапы это костыли, бессмысленно и плохо.

Comment: @aepot если временный файл записался наполовину, то старый файл по-прежнему останется живой — его ведь никто не записывал

Comment: @andreymal а, вот вы про что. Понял. Ну так это по сути то же самое, только с другого боку. Только в вашем случае присутствует копирование данных (или удаление перед переименованием), а в моём - нет. А идея по сути та же самая.

Comment: @aepot нормальные ОС позволяют переименовать без удаления и гарантируют атомарность этой операции. А ненормальными ОС не надо пользоваться, переходите на нормальные)

Comment: @andreymal нет. Только винда, только хардкор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использовал такой алгоритм: записывал во временный файл В в целевой папке, проверял его, переименовывал целевой файл Ц во временное имя, переименовывал временный файл В в целевое имя, удалял временный файл Ц.

Перед открытием проверял наличие файла, если нет, то искал В или переименованный Ц.

А предыстория такая. Небольшой конфигурационной файл в маленькой локальной сети. Никак не думал, что может что-то случится, но где-то через месяц приложение свой файл не нашло. Так что пришлось придумать и реализовать такую схему. Пару лет уже работает без сбоев.

Comment: Rotabor спасибо большое!